# bootstrap 4 columns seem to block off rest of columns to take up the full row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want 2 divs on the same row. One taking up 8 columns and the next taking up 4 columns.

However, It is automatically blocking off the remaining columns in the row, causing every div with col-xx-xx to take up a full row. Here is what I mean:

[image]
[image]

How do I get it to stop blocking off the rest of the row so I can have both divs on the same row?

Making the div with 4 cols take up less space by deleting its contents doesn't work. Neither does turning the div with 4 cols into a col-xs-3.

Code:

```
<div id="shops-section">
   <div id="map" #map></div>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let shop of result?.nearbyShops">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="shop-details">
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                     <h5>{{ shop.name }}</h5>
                     <h6>{{ shop.address }}</h6>
                     <button id="open-hours" type="button" class="btn btn-default">OPEN HOURS</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                     <div class="icon-container">
                        <img class="icon card-icon review-icon" src="images/sad-face.png">
                        <h6>10</h6>
                        <img class="icon card-icon review-icon" src="images/happy-face.png">
                        <h6>21</h6>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
    #map {
        height: 325px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    #map > div {
        max-width: none !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    }


  .shop-details {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
        padding:18px;
    }

    .shop-details h5 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: $primary-500;
        font-weight: 200;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .shop-details h6 {
        color: $primary-500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #open-hours {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 12px;
        color: $accent;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid $accent;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul {
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .icon-container {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 0;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .icon-container img {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .icon-container h6 {
        font-weight: 200;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .icon {
        height: 32px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

Comment: You need to wrap columns that add up to 12 inside a `div` with a class of `row`.

Comment: I was just about to say the same :)

Comment: if you have 2 cols one `col-md-8` and one `col-md-4`, it's normal for them to block the rest of the content. Try changing the size so the rest of the content can fit on the same row.

Comment: @Enijar They are wrapped by a row - just added more of my html to show that. Cheers

Comment: @ZombieChowder But they add up to 12 columns so should fit in one row.

Comment: Using the code you provided with Bootstrap does not reproduce your problem. The columns are displayed properly. The issue may be in another part of your CSS. You could put your code in a jsfiddle so we can see better.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins consider leaving space for any other elements in that same row, which means that your columns shouldn't be split 8 by 4. Maybe you should provide space and make them 6 by 2 and give the rest of the column space for the other elements.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins Your icon images are taking more width then the container has , so it's breaking the layout. Try adding some width to it, or make it adjust to its container.

Comment: The `col-*` should be the immediate children of the `row`, not `row`>`shop-details`>`col*..`. `shop-details` is negating the negative padding of the Bootstrap `row` making your columns wrap.

Comment: @ZimSystem yes, fixing that fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `col-*`'s need to be the *immediate* children of the `row`. `row`>`shop-details`>`col*` won't work because `shop-details` is overriding the negative margins (-15px) of the Bootstrap `row` making your columns wrap.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the isseu is due to

```
.shop-details {
     padding:18px;
}
```

which makes the cols too wide to fit across the page. i.e it can no  longer fit in the full 12.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the padding didn't fix it.